# Perl Hash of Hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to Perl, and I am trying something with a hash.  I have a hash of hashes like below:

```
%HoH =   
(
    "Test1" => { checked => 1, mycmd => run1 },
    "Test2" => { checked => 1, mycmd => run2 },
)
```

Using the below code I will get the output given below:

```
for $family ( keys %HoH ) 
{
    print "$family: ";
    for $role ( keys %{ $HoH{$family} } ) 
    {
        print "$role=$HoH{$family}{$role} ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Test1: checked=1 mycmd=run1 
Test2: checked=1 mycmd=run2
```

My question is, how can I access individual `checked` & `cmd` separately?  By accessing separately, I can compare what is checked and do my task.

Comment: What do you mean? Isnt `$HoH{"Test1"}{checked}` what you want?

Comment: Doesn't your output say "cmd", not "mycmd"? Do you mean, see if Test1 is checked, then see what the command is? Something like `if ($HoH{Test1}->{checked}) { system($HoH{Test1}{cmd}) }`?

Comment: Also, please begin your code with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and fix anything they complain about. It will make your code cleaner and easier to debug. (In particular, you should add quotes around the strings `run1` and `run2` and declare your loop variables as local with `for my $var (...)`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for my $family ( keys %HoH )
{
    if ($HoH{$family}->{checked}) {
         # Do what you want...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dolmen , This is exactly what i wanted .

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight-forward to just use the keyword(s) literally:

```
%HoH =   
(
    "Test1" => { checked => 1, cmd => run1 },
    "Test2" => { checked => 1, cmd => run2 },
);
if ($HoH{"Test1"}{checked}) {
print "Test1 is Checked with cmd: " . $HoH{"Test1"}{cmd} . "\n";
}
```

> Test1 is Checked with cmd: run1

Did I understand your question correctly?